# Terminal Prompt Not Changing To '>>>' When Executing Python File

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, command-prompt, prompt

I am running the following command on terminal:

```
python SpellingCorrector.py
```

No error is thrown by terminal and it simply progresses to the next line with the same prompt showing my current working directory, rather than the Python `'>>>'` terminal prompt.

I would like to run a function within the program with an argument and I only have the option to attempt that as such:

```
[my/current/directory/]$ correction('speling')
```

This then throws the error

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'speling'`

I'm guessing I need to run it with this prompt in order for it to work:

```
>>> correction('speling')
```

The Python version is 2.7.5.
Does anyone know why the prompt is not changing when I run the program or how I can run the function?

Comment: Why would you think it should change at all? The Python script is executed and control is returned to the shell.

Comment: is correction is function in SpellingCorrector.py ?

Comment: Because the Python program is run as any other program, and once the script exits so does the `python` command. Running scripts that way is *not* interactive, as [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/) should have told you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to execute your script in the interactive mode, like the following :

```
python -i SpellingCorrector.py
```

and then execute your function from there :

```
correction('speling')
```

Answer (score 4):

You are launching the program instead of launching python interpreter.

To use interpreter, launch it as follows (without arguments):

`python`

then use `import SpellingCorrector`to import your program to interpreter.
Now you can use its functions etc.

Please note, that import statement has no `.py` extension.

Comment: or use @marsouf answer, it's also valid

Answer (score 0):

The `python script.py` command simply executes the script and returns control to the shell, which is not what you want.

You could use [`ipython`](https://ipython.org/)'s [`%run`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html#magic-run) command to run a python script from *inside the interpeter*:

```
%run ./script.py
```

> This is similar to running at a system prompt `python file args`, but
>   with the advantage of giving you IPython’s tracebacks, and of loading
>   all variables into your interactive namespace for further use.